# Local variables in C and Java

Tags: java, c, local-variables

I know C and Java uses lexical scoping and the scope of a variable is within the block where it was defined.
See the code of Java:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          int j = 0;
          while(j==0){ 
            int j =1;
            System.out.println(j);
          }
    }
}
```

This program give an error "variable j is already defined in method main"

See the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j==0){ 
        int j =1;
        printf("%d",j);
    }
}
```

Here we get an infinite loop "11111111.............." As output.

Why does the C compiler not complain about the j variable as Java do?

Comment: @TonyTannous `C doesn't even know about your variable names` ? if the compiler does not know the variables name how it can produce code ?

Comment: The only relevant matter here is the language definition: is it legal to declare a variable in an inner scope that masks the variable in an outer scope. Different languages have different rules. It is nothing to do with "metadata".

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward answer of why a C compiler permits that construction, but a Java compiler does not, is that the construction is legal in C (and in most lexically-scoped languages that I've used), but is expressly [not legal in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4).

I do not find the rationale in the language specification to be compelling ("it would be impossible to distinguish between the declared entities using only simple names") - well, yeah, but that's what the lexical structure is doing for you.  But nevertheless, that's how the language is.

On the positive side, accidental obscuring of identifiers is a source of errors that cannot exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because C compiler would only launch a warning to you instead of an error...
What you did is not "wrong", but Java still stop compiling because calling a variable with the same name within the same function is a very bad practice and most probably **not** intentional.
If you change the value of j variable in the while() scope, the outside j will not be affected by the changes.

Comment: In other words, it's an error in Java because the Java designers decided to make it an error.

Comment: Exactly as you said ;)